# Treatment of donations of appreciated stock to a IRC §501(c)(7) Social Club?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, estate-settlement

What differences or special considerations are there in IRS tax handling of bequests made to a §501(c)(7) social club, compared to the same bequest made to a private party or a §501(c)(3)

In particular how is a donation of appreciated stock handled, and what basis would apply to the stock?

I am aware of https://www.irs.gov/Charities-&-Non-Profits/Other-Non-Profits/Guidelines-for-Tax-Exempt-Social-Clubs-Internal-Revenue-Manual

Comment: If this is a question about the basis of the stock that the  501(c)(7) social club receives as a bequest, then it is off-topic for this site. If the question is about the taxable estate for Federal or State Estate Tax purposes, then it is worth noting that less than 1% of estates pay any Federal Estate Tax at all because they are smaller than $5.4M, the current exemption. If the estate in question is larger, hiring a competent attorney is far better than relying on opinions on this site.

Answer (score 1):

If cash donations are not deductable, stock contributions aren't either and I believe the same rules apply as for a private party.

Comment: If a private party inherits stock, the basis is set at time of death.  Is a 501(c)7 different?

Comment: If the stock is transferred, are taxes due at time of transfer? Where are these rules written down?

Comment: @Bryce  you are tacking on 2 different questions.

Comment: If you have additional questions, please start a new Question for each.